# Не могу 2 подряд загрузить данные в БД

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Сабж. Имею такие модели.

```cs
    public class Video
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<AuthorComment> AuthorComments { get; set; } = new();
    }
    
        public class AuthorComment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Video> Videos { get; set; } = new();
    }
```

Код которым я связываю объекты.

```cs
                using (Context app = new Context())
                {
                    if (author.Videos.Where(i => i.Url == video.Url).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        author.Videos.Add(video);

                        app.AuthorComments.Update(author);

                    }
                    app.SaveChanges();
                }
```

При первом выполнении этого кода все хорошо. А при втором ошибка.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: "An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details."

MySqlException: Duplicate entry '16-1' for key 'authorcommentvideo.PRIMARY'
```

То есть когда программа выполняет 2 раз этот кусок то вылетает ошибка. Причем когда я снова пытаюсь выполнить код берет тот объект на котором в прошлый раз была ошибка и добавляет его, а на следующем снова ошибка. Такое чувство будто бы пытается добавить старый объект который уже есть в бд. В моем случае меняется только `AuthorComment` и он каждый раз пересоздается.

Comment: Можете предоставить где происходит объявление video?

Comment: Происходило в самом начале. Я думаю это потому что прошлые данные сохранялись в контексте. Я уже удалил эти связи и буду дальше без них делать.

Comment: А попробуйте отказаться от `Update`, работайте с объектами так, как с обычной коллекцией, а в конце просто сохраняйте изменения.

Comment: Документацию [DbSet.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-7.0) внимательно изучали? Этот метод начинает отслеживание переданной сущности и всех связанных сущностей. Очевидно, что какая-то из этих сущностей помечается не как Modified, а как Added (подробности там описаны) и EF пытается вставить её. / Что именно нужно изменить в вашем коде сказать невозможно. Слишком мало информации приведено.